# How to use/acess django rest api in python console application

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am new to Python and Django frameworks. I have Rest API's developed using Django framework, how to access Rest API's and display response in Python Console application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go all the way you need a http client in python, A popular one is [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

to use this in terminal you can just do

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://localhost/api/myview')
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
print(response.json)
```

The drawback to this is that the server actually has to be running, if you want to play around without starting a server you have more options!

You can also use the test clients built into Django, like this

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

client = APIClient()
response = client.get('/api/myview/')
```

Or even construct a Request and call the view directly.

```
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from myproject.views import MyViewClass

view = MyViewClass.as_view()

factory = APIRequestFactory()
request = factory.get('/api/myview/')
response = view(request)
```